# How to keep track of state in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, state, monads

I would like to create a system that has to keep track of a changing state in order to discover an outcome. The format of the input data is a list of strings that I break down into chars.

For example ['ynynyy','ynynyn',...]

In an imperative style the logic would be as follows:

```
yCount=0,xCount=0,yTotal=0,nTotal=0

for x in input:
  for y in x:
    if y is 'y':
      yCount++
    else:
      nCount++
    if yCount is 10:
       yTotal++
    if nCount is 10:
       nTotal++
    if yCount is 10 or nCount is 10:
       yCount=0
       nCount=0
```

The use of mutable variables makes it difficult for me to translate the pattern to Haskell.

I am currently working to try and create a solution using nested functions:

```
main = do
  parseInputData input

parseInputData :: [String] -> IO () --would like to write solution to file
parseInputData x = do
  let result = map getSingleValue (lines input)

getSingleValue :: [Char] -> String --would like to return string representation of outcome
getSingleValue (x:xs)
  | x == 'y' .. --update state and continue
  | x == 'n' .. --update state and continue
  | otherwise .. --return final state
```

I am very rusty and out of practice with Haskell syntax and also functional programming in general. I am aware of the State monad but unsure how to correctly implement it.

Any ideas shared that would get me going in the right direction or help me adjust my train of thought which is a bit stuck in imperative would allow me to produce a solution!

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: No need for the state monad. Just use list recursion and pass through the state variables as arguments. Or make a record that contains all four, and pass that record as a single value. Or then use that with a fold.

Comment: It seems you essentially want to count the number of y's and n's. For this you can just `concat` the lists of characters into one, `filter` the list into the appropriate character, and then take the `length`. There's usually a purely functional solution to most such problems, you shouldn't reach for state as a first impulse.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for your inputs. Each element of the array needs to have the ys and ns counted separately. The order of the ys and ns per element also matters.

Answer (score 3):

One can do this without a `State` monad. In fact a `State` monad roughly makes it easier to make passing the state implicit, such that you do not *manually* need to carry it from one item to another. Furthermore a `State` is often better, since one can define helper functions on a generic `State` that are thus useful.

It might however be more useful to first try to implement this without a `State`, and thus simply pass the state of the outcome from one function to the next one. We can define a data type `Outcome` that stores the four numbers:

```
data Outcome = Outcome
  { yCount :: Int
  , nCount :: Int
  , yTotal :: Int
  , nTotal :: Int
  } deriving Show
```

Then our initial state is:

```
initial :: Outcome
initial = Outcome 0 0 0 0
```

Next we thus can define a function that will "normalize" the values in case on of the values hits 10:

```
normalize :: Outcome -> Outcome
normalize (Outcome y0 n0 y1 n1) | y10 || n10 = Outcome 0 0 y1' n1'
    where y10 = y0 == 10
          n10 = n0 == 10
          y1' = y1 + fromEnum y10
          n1' = n1 + fromEnum n10
normalize o = o
```

Now we can thus make a function that takes an input element, and updates the `Outcome` accordingly:

```
updateInput :: Outcome -> Char -> Outcome
updateInput o@Outcome {yCount=y0} 'y' = normalize o{yCount=y0+1}
updateInput o@Outcome {nCount=n0} 'n' = normalize o{nCount=n0+1}
```

So now we can make use of [**`foldl :: Foldable f => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> f a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) to start with an initial `Outcome`, and then each time take an item of a list, and update the `Outcome` accordingly until we have the final outcome. So we can define an `updateSequence` with:

```
updateSequence :: Foldable f => Outcome -> f Char -> Outcome
updateSequence = foldl updateInput
```

For example if we use `initial` as initial `Outcome` and we pass `"ynynyy"` as string we get:

```
Prelude> updateSequence initial "ynynyy"
Outcome {yCount = 4, nCount = 2, yTotal = 0, nTotal = 0}
```

So we can use another `foldl` to work over a list of lists (or more generic `Foldable`s):

```
updateSequence2 :: (Foldable f, Foldable g) => Outcome -> f (g Char) -> Outcome
updateSequence2 = foldl updateSequence
```

Then we can obtain the final value with:

```
Prelude> updateSequence2 initial ["ynynyy","ynynyn"]
Outcome {yCount = 7, nCount = 5, yTotal = 0, nTotal = 0}
Prelude> updateSequence2 initial ["ynynyy","ynynyn", "nnnnyn"]
Outcome {yCount = 0, nCount = 0, yTotal = 0, nTotal = 1}
```